# Account not found for tombstone account (Creating a notebook instance)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm trying to setup my GCP account, so that I can use a cloud GPU to run my Tensorflow projects.

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new) guide from google, but for some reason, when try to create a new notebook instance, I get the following error:

> Account not found for tombstone account.

I have absolutely no idea what a tombstone account is, and how I would create one. Google doesn't mention anything about this, nor in the guide, so I really hope someone could point me in the right direction here.

Comment: A tombstone is a container object consisting of the deleted objects from AD. These objects have not been physically removed from the database. When an AD object, such as a user is deleted, the object technically remains in the directory for a given period of time; known as the Tombstone Lifetime. [1](https://support.storagecraft.com/s/article/Understanding-Tombstones-Active-Directory-and-How-To-Protect-It?language=en_US).  The issue might be related to the Service Account you are using to create the AI notebook instance. Please try to change the service account and provide us the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Account not found for tombstone account." is seen normally when you delete a Service Account and try to use it or recreated it after a short period of time.
I would try to create a new Service Account with a different name and specify it when you create the new AI Platform Notebooks [instance](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_403_forbidden_error).